# one simple mysql query(its big table) to find distinct values with respect to one column

Tags: mysql

Below is my table structure.

```
options_id  user_id option_id  option_value  date_added           added_by
        1         0         1  15            2015-07-05 13:58:25         1  
        2         0         2  trigger       2015-07-05 15:34:10         1
        3         0         3  silver        2015-07-05 15:35:09         1 
        4         1         1  5             2015-07-05 15:34:45         1
```

I need a simple query to choose distinct option_id, but condition here is,if a user has his own option_id(here option_id 1 is there for user 1) then choose it else choose for user_id=0.

So for user 1 I am expecting output as,

options_id     user_id     option_id     option_value              date_added     added_by

---

```
     2        0          2  trigger       2015-07-05 15:34:10         1
     3        0          3  silver        2015-07-05 15:35:09         1 
     4        1          1  5             2015-07-05 15:34:45         1
```

but for user 2,

options_id     user_id     option_id     option_value              date_added     added_by

---

```
     1        0          1  15            2015-07-05 13:58:25         1 
     2        0          2  trigger       2015-07-05 15:34:10         1
     3        0          3  silver        2015-07-05 15:35:09         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want all options for a given user.  Then, you want all options from user 0 where the option does not exist for the user.

Here is an approach that uses `union all`:

```
select t.*
from options t
where user_id = $user_id
union all
select t.*
from options t
where user_id = 0 and
      not exists (select 1
                  from options t2
                  where t2.user_id = $user_id and t2.option_id = t.option_id
                 );
```

For best performance, you want an index on `options(user_id, option_id)` and `options(option_id)`.

Comment: @AnishCharles . . . `union all` is fast.  `union` is not, because it removes duplicates.  With the specified indexes, this is probably as fast as you can get the query to run.